# excel - if value grater than, use that value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007

I am having problems with my excel function. I want to:

if value 1 is greater than value 2, then write value 1 in a cell. If value 2 is greater than value 1, then write value 2 in the cell.

Currently, I have this:

```
=IF(B5>D4, "B5","D4")
```

With this I just get an error that my formula contains errors.. Can someplease please advise me what to do?

Comment: your formula should work in general, however two possible issues: 1. if you want it to write the contents of `B5` or `D4`, remove the quotes. 2. make sure B5 and D4 contain numeric values. Maybe try using the formula wizard to get around syntax issues.

Answer (score 1):

That's an easy one, use the MAX function:

> =MAX(B5,D4);

and if you want to generalize this to return the k-th largest value, you can use:

> =LARGE(array,k)

k=2 would return the second largest value in the array, and k=1 would be the equivelant of the MAX function